# Making cross domain requests with Jquery, CORS, and Apache

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache

I want to make a cross domain request between two servers/domains that I own.

So far:
In server1/domain1 I have Apache running and I enabled mod_headers, added "Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "myotherdomain.com", and restarted apache.

In server2/domain2 I have a node.js webapp running and I do the following ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "domain1.com/myproject/test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {test: "test"},
    success: function() {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function() {
    alert("error");
}
```

The test.php file simply echos the post variable test that is passed in the ajax.

What do I need to do in order to make this ajax return a "success"?

Comment: I think jsonp should help you out...

Comment: @AmitHorakeri added dataType: "jsonp", right after my data: {test: "test"},
and no change.

Comment: Amit, JSONP is a totally different approach to solving this problem.

Comment: Also JSONP doesn't support `POST`, It only support `GET` request